# How can I set up Phabricator to run my django unit tests?

Tags: django, phabricator, django-unittest

It seems like it *could* be pretty simple to set up Arcanist to run unit tests in a Django project.  But [the only documentation](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint_unit/) on setting up unit tests that seems to exist says that I'll have to write a php class to extend `ArcanistUnitTestEngine`.

I was hoping for something like putting:

```
"unit.engine" : "DjangoUnitTestEngine"
```

or:

```
"unit.engine" : "PythonUnitTestEngine"
```

into .arcconfig.

Does that exist?

Comment: `arc linters` will show what current lint options are, I don't see anything native for Django.

Comment: I'm not worried about linting, I was trying to get something going for unit testing.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a lot of Test Engine available yet but there is a `PytestTestEngine` defined (recently) here:

https://secure.phabricator.com/diffusion/ARC/browse/master/src/unit/engine/PytestTestEngine.php

Which looks like an Engine for PyTest (http://pytest.org) which isn't the default for Django I believe but you could look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django for that.

Otherwise you would have to either:

- Write your own TestEngine
- Do your test server-side using Harbormaster-Drydock
- Do your test server side on a third-party CI tool that integrates with Phabricator like Jenkins

Comment: ooo this looks promising, thank!  I'll try it out and accept your answer if I can get it working